# How do i load images dataset using tf.keras.utils.get_file

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, dataset

I;m working with cifar-10 dataset and i need the dataset available publicly, so i pushed it to gitlab. i want to load this dataset in my code, after some digging i found an example where they used tf.keras.utils.get_file() which looked perfect but when i try to load my dataset i get a NotADirectoryError. but it loads just fine with the example i found online which is confusing, can someone please explain why it wouldn't work for my dataset?

here's the example i found that works, the is_dir() returns true

```
import pathlib

data_root_orig = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
'flower_photos','https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',untar=True)
    data_root = pathlib.Path(data_root_orig)
    print(data_root.is_dir()
)
```

here's my dataset I'm trying to load. Initially throws train_data is not a directory, when i try again it seems to work but is_dir is false and i'm unable to get to the files in my dataset

```
import pathlib
import tensorflow as tf
data_root_orig = tf.keras.utils.get_file('train',
                                         'https://gitlab.com/StephenAI/osato-file/raw/master/train.zip',
                                        untar=True, archive_format='zip')
data_root = pathlib.Path(data_root_orig)
print(data_root, type(data_root),data_root.is_dir())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# download IMDb movie review dataset
import tensorflow as tf
dataset = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    fname="aclImdb.tar.gz", 
    origin="http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz", 
    extract=True,
)
```

//reference: https://github.com/amaiya/ktrain

Answer (score 1):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
url = 'https://.zip'
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('dataset', url, extract=True)
# if url = 'https://tgz' => untar=True
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg')))
```

for tensorflow 2 you may find dataset directly in [~/.keras/datasets](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33501) and use it as you want to

doc [tf.keras.utils.get_file](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/get_file)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I had to take other a slightly different path, you can do as I did and see if it serves you well.. 
So I uploaded the .zip file in my Google Drive account, mounted it to Colab, and then i used `patoolib.extract_archive(zip_file_path, outdir='destination_folder')` and continued coding using the images from the destination_folder .. 
of course you're gonna need to install the library using `!pip install patool` and then import it using `import patoolib`.